# how to get the raw html code use superagent before 301 redirects?

Tags: node.js, superagent

here is the site http://sf.gg, when open it, it will be redirected to the site https://segmentfault.com

use curl I can get the html code of http://sf.gg:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know how to get it use the node module [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#following-redirects)?

I see [Following redirects](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#following-redirects), but I don't know how to use it, or it's the right way to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*SuperAgent* considers 3xx responses as [errors](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#error-handling) by default.
So you have to handle error to get the content of the page before the redirection occurs. We can force *SuperAgent* to not follow the redirection with `.redirects(0)` and print the response:

```
const superagent = require('superagent') 

superagent
  .get('http://sf.gg')
  .redirects(0)
  .on('error', err => {
    console.log(err.response.text)
  })
  .end()
```

Or you can use `.ok()` to act more precisely on the response:

```
superagent
  .get('http://sf.gg')
  .redirects(0)
  .ok(res => {
    if (res.status === 301)
      console.log(res.text)
  })
  .end()
```